# Difficulty with total derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to introduce myself to the total derivative Dt in the documentation tutorial/TotalDerivatives. But I ran into what I think is a problem.

There seems to be a serious problem in the documentation tutorial/TotalDerivatives. It says that Clear[y] removes the definition for the derivative of y. But it doesn't.

```
Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

2 x + 2 y Dt[y, x] + 2 z Dt[z, x]
```

Then I did:

```
y /: Dt[y, x] = 0

0
```

Followed by:

```
Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

2 x + 2 z Dt[z, x]
```

Then I tried to clear y.

```
Clear[y]
```

But look what happens when I try Dt again. It doesn't return the first answer again.

```
Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

2 x + 2 z Dt[z, x]
```

Now I quit the kernel and start again, not re-evaluating the notebook, and use the TagUnset rule, which does work.

```
Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

2 x + 2 y Dt[y, x] + 2 z Dt[z, x]
```

TagSet again:

```
y /: Dt[y, x] = 0

0
```

Evaluate again:

```
Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

2 x + 2 z Dt[z, x]
```

Then TagUnset:

```
y /: Dt[y, x] =.
```

Evaluate again and it works properly.

```
Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

2 x + 2 y Dt[y, x] + 2 z Dt[z, x]
```

Is this a bug in the documentation or am I missing something?

Comment: What about `ClearAll`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer It seems that `ClearAll` works for this example in version 8, but not in version 10.1. Perhaps there is some caching going on in the evaluation of `Dt[x^2+y^2+z^2,x]`, because `Clear` and `ClearAll` do indeed clear the `UpValues` of `y`, as the documentation says they should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I speculate about the reason for this behavior in the comment, but no matter whether that's the correct explanation, I would say that the documentation isn't wrong because I can verify the removal of the `UpValues` using `Definition`. However, this doesn't solve the problem.

As a workaround that requires less typing than the `UnSet` approach in the question, I would suggest using [`Remove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Remove.html) as follows:

```
y /: Dt[y, x] = 0

(* ==> 0 *)

Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

(* ==> 2 x + 2 z Dt[z, x] *)

Definition[y]

(* ==> y /: Dt[y, x] = 0 *)

Clear[y]

Definition[y]

(* ==> Null *)

Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

(* ==> 2 x + 2 z Dt[z, x] *)

Remove[y]

Dt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x]

(* ==> 2 x + 2 y Dt[y, x] + 2 z Dt[z, x] *)
```